# Using CSS to replace text dynamically

Tags: css

In following HTML snippet, I am trying to modify the  text dynamically using CSS.

```
<li id="onroad" class="onroad boxSizing" data-stageid="4" data-invalidot="1" data-desc="Heading your way">
                <span class="material-icons ui-state-default ui-state-active" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <h4 class="text" role="none">On Road</h4>
                    <span class="line ui-state-default ui-state-active" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</li>
```

My CSS snippet is,

```
#trackerDiv>#trackerNav>ol#tracker.delivery li#onroad span.ui-state-active  h4 {visibility: hidden;}
#trackerDiv>#trackerNav>ol#tracker.delivery li#onroad span.ui-state-active h4:before {visibility: visible;position: absolute;content: "Complete";}
```

So my ask is without using JS/Jquery to dynamically change the text based on "ui-state-active" class presence. CSS looks alright but it ain't working.

If above CSS executes correctly, it should replace "On Road" to "Complete"

Comment: Dynamically changed by user event such as clicking?

Comment: You cannot make the child elements visible if the host element has `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: @connexo Actually, yes you can. `visibility` /= `opacity`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSS is incorrect, the `h4` is not a child of the `span` it's a sibling so use `+`, like so

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li#onroad span.ui-state-active+h4 {
  visibility: hidden;
}

li#onroad span.ui-state-active+h4:before {
  visibility: visible;
  content: "Complete";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="onroad" class="onroad boxSizing" data-stageid="4" data-invalidot="1" data-desc="Heading your way">
    <span class="material-icons ui-state-default ui-state-active" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <h4 class="text" role="none">On Road</h4>
    <span class="line ui-state-default ui-state-active" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</ul>
```